# Prevent loopback's attempt to load certain files in server/boot/

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

My OS adds files prefixed with `._` when I sometimes edit a text file.  This means that my `server/boot/` directory contains a bunch of `._` files that aren't JavaScript.  For example, if I create a script called `foo-bar.js`, there might be a corresponding file `._foo-bar.js`.

These `._` files are causing my bootstrap to break, because my app attempts to load them as valid JS (see error message below).  How can I prevent this from happening?  Is there a place where I can configure a RegExp to exclude certain files from being auto-loaded?

My solution for the time being is to manually delete `._` files, which is annoying.  I'd just like to ignore them.

```
Failed loading boot script: /home/myuser/myapp/server/boot/._foo-bar.js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at /home/myuser/myapp/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:263:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at runScripts (/home/myuser/myapp/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:260:8)
/home/myuser/myapp/server/boot/._foo-bar.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
```

Cheers, and many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe we support ignoring files ATM. Please post a feature request in the LoopBack Boot repo with your use case. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-boot.

Answer (score 0):

One work around is to merge ._ files to its native file using [dot_clean](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dot_clean.1.html).